# Power BI matrix table - Column headers

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling, measure

I have the following matrix table:

Visual Rows:

- Date -> Month

Visual Columns

- Empty

Visual Values

- Value 1 (is a measure)
- Value 2 (is a measure)
- Value 3 (is a measure)
- Value 4 (is a measure)

Currently I get the follwing table:

```html
Month       | Value 1  | Value 2 | Value 3  | Value 4 |
------------------------------------------------------
January     |    47    |    63   |    47    |    63   |
February    |    50    |    42   |    24    |    33   |
March       |    38    |    37   |    75    |    42   |
April       |    12    |    65   |    32    |    39   |
May         |    45    |    30   |    28    |    42   |
June        |    67    |    41   |    36    |    50   |
```

I would like to add a column so I can devide the values in 2 categories:

1. Category 1

   - Value 1
   - Value 2
2. Category 2

   - Value 3
   - Value 4

So I would get a matrix like the following:

```html
            |     Category 1     |      Category 2    |
Month       | Value 1  | Value 2 | Value 3  | Value 4 |
------------------------------------------------------
January     |    47    |    63   |    47    |    63   |
February    |    50    |    42   |    24    |    33   |
March       |    38    |    37   |    75    |    42   |
April       |    12    |    65   |    32    |    39   |
May         |    45    |    30   |    28    |    42   |
June        |    67    |    41   |    36    |    50   |
```

Is this somehow possible with dax measure?

Thank you for any Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a disconnected table like this named My Table (do not create any relationships to it)

[image]

Create a measure like this:

```
Measure = 
VAR x= SELECTEDVALUE('My Table'[Measure])
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    x = "Measure 1", "I'm measure 1",
    x = "Measure 2", "I'm measure 2",
    x = "Measure 3", "I'm measure 3",
    x = "Measure 4", "I'm measure 4",
    BLANK()
)
```

Add everything to a matrix and ensure you drill down on columns

[image]